# Restore Gnome Panel to Default Configuration

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

Is there any way to restore the gnome panel configuration back to default?

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel
```

And then make gnome-panel die a violent death:

```
killall gnome-panel
```

At least, that's the theory.